# Postfix MySQL Error 111

Tags: mysql, debian, postfix-mta, webmail

Ok so im setting up a postfix sql connection and for some weird reason, the same account that is accessing the previous two maps is now refusing the connection to 127.0.0.1. Two Connections are already working with the same credentials.

#### The first file the one with the issue (111)

> user = exampleadmin
>
> password = bgfoenawox
>
> hosts = 127.0.0.1
>
> dbname = exampleserver
>
> query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'

This gives me the following error in putty,

> postmap: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1:Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
>
> postmap: fatal: table mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf: query error: Connection refused

#### Working virtual email maps.

> user = exampleadmin
>
> password = bgfoenawox
>
> hosts = 127.0.0.1
>
> dbname = exampleserver
>
> query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'

This gives me the following result in putty,

```
 1
```

#### Working virtual domain maps

> user = exampleadmin
>
> password = bgfoenawox
>
> hosts = 127.0.0.1
>
> dbname = exampleserver
>
> query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='%s'

This gives me the following result in putty,

```
 1
```

I am following this guide here. [Postfix Guide](https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/connecting-postfix-to-the-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer!

Finally, that didnt take long.

## If anyone is having this issue, please try this.

> nano /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

#### Change the hosts to

> From : 127.0.0.1 > HOSTNAME e.g. server54

#### This will enable the connection to the localhost. And show the correct postmap.

> postmap -q youremailhere@email.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

#### Result?

> Your email address (example@example.com)